# How to write ''Listed Records'' in a text file?

Tags: c++, output

I am doing a project and I want to know how I can keep the records in a text file, the information that I can see in the second section (List Records).

```
#include <stdio.h> ///for input output functions like printf, scanf
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h> ///for windows related functions (not important)
#include <string.h>  ///string operations

/** List of Global Variable */
COORD coord = {0,0}; /// top-left corner of window

/**
    function : gotoxy
    @param input: x and y coordinates
    @param output: moves the cursor in specified position of console
*/
void gotoxy(int x,int y){
    coord.X = x; coord.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),coord);
}

/** Main function started */



int main(){
    ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("program3data.txt");
    FILE *fp, *ft; /// file pointers
    char another, choice;

    /** structure that represent a employee */
    struct emp{
        char name[40]; ///name of employee
        int age; /// age of employee
        float bs; /// basic salary of employee
};

struct emp e; /// structure variable creation

char empname[40]; /// string to store name of the employee

long int recsize; /// size of each record of employee

/** open the file in binary read and write mode
* if the file EMP.DAT already exists then it open that file in read write mode
* if the file doesn't exit it simply create a new copy
*/
fp = fopen("EMP.DAT","rb+");
if(fp == NULL){
    fp = fopen("EMP.DAT","wb+");
    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("Connot open file");
        exit(1);
    }
}

/// sizeo of each record i.e. size of structure variable e
recsize = sizeof(e);

/// infinite loop continues untile the break statement encounter
while(1){
    system("cls"); ///clear the console window
    gotoxy(30,10); /// move the cursor to postion 30, 10 from top-left corner
    printf("1. Add Record"); /// option for add record
    gotoxy(30,12);
    printf("2. List Records"); /// option for showing existing record
    gotoxy(30,14);
    printf("3. Modify Records"); /// option for editing record
    gotoxy(30,16);
    printf("4. Delete Records"); /// option for deleting record
    gotoxy(30,18);
    printf("5. Exit"); /// exit from the program
    gotoxy(30,20);
    printf("Your Choice: "); /// enter the choice 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
    fflush(stdin); /// flush the input buffer
    choice  = getche(); /// get the input from keyboard
    switch(choice){
        case '1':  /// if user press 1
            system("cls");
            fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END); /// search the file and move cursor to end of the file
                                    /// here 0 indicates moving 0 distance from the end of the file

            another = 'y';
            while(another == 'y'){ /// if user want to add another record
                printf("\nEnter name: ");
                scanf("%s",e.name);
                printf("\nEnter age: ");
                scanf("%d", &e.age);
                printf("\nEnter basic salary: ");
                scanf("%f", &e.bs);

                fwrite(&e,recsize,1,fp); /// write the record in the file

                printf("\nAdd another record(y/n) ");
                fflush(stdin);
                another = getche();
            }
            break;
        case '2':
            system("cls");
            rewind(fp); ///this moves file cursor to start of the file
            while(fread(&e,recsize,1,fp)==1){ /// read the file and fetch the record one record per fetch
                printf("\n%s %d %.2f",e.name,e.age,e.bs); /// print the name, age and basic salary
            }
            getch();
            break;

        case '3':  /// if user press 3 then do editing existing record
            system("cls");
            another = 'y';
            while(another == 'y'){
                printf("Enter the employee name to modify: ");
                scanf("%s", empname);
                rewind(fp);
                while(fread(&e,recsize,1,fp)==1){ /// fetch all record from file
                    if(strcmp(e.name,empname) == 0){ ///if entered name matches with that in file
                        printf("\nEnter new name,age and bs: ");
                        scanf("%s%d%f",e.name,&e.age,&e.bs);
                        fseek(fp,-recsize,SEEK_CUR); /// move the cursor 1 step back from current position
                        fwrite(&e,recsize,1,fp); /// override the record
                        break;
                    }
                }
                printf("\nModify another record(y/n)");
                fflush(stdin);
                another = getche();
            }
            break;
        case '4':
            system("cls");
            another = 'y';
            while(another == 'y'){
                printf("\nEnter name of employee to delete: ");
                scanf("%s",empname);
                ft = fopen("Temp.dat","wb");  /// create a intermediate file for temporary storage
                rewind(fp); /// move record to starting of file
                while(fread(&e,recsize,1,fp) == 1){ /// read all records from file
                    if(strcmp(e.name,empname) != 0){ /// if the entered record match
                        fwrite(&e,recsize,1,ft); /// move all records except the one that is to be deleted to temp file
                        }
                    }
                    fclose(fp);
                    fclose(ft);
                    remove("EMP.DAT"); /// remove the orginal file
                    rename("Temp.dat","EMP.DAT"); /// rename the temp file to original file name
                    fp = fopen("EMP.DAT", "rb+");
                    printf("Delete another record(y/n)");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    another = getche();
                }
                break;
            case '5':
                fclose(fp);  /// close the file
                exit(0); /// exit from the program
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Read this before posting please sscce.org

Comment: You probably should've started your homework sooner.

Comment: You should factor the `system("cls");` to before `switch` statement or, IMO, out of the program entirely.  When `cases` contain the same code, the code may be a candidate to place before or after the `switch` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep records in a file, you write them to the file:

```
fwrite(&variable, 1, sizeof(record), file_pointer);
```

To read a record from a file:

```
fread(&variable, 1, sizeof(record), file_pointer);
```

To position to record Y in the file:

```
  fseek(file_pointer, (Y * sizeof(record)), SEEK_SET);
```

If this is not helpful, please clarify "keep in a file", or state why it is not helpful.